# Auto Increment for Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to create a sequence and a trigger to auto-increment the primary key on a table but I have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create the table and the sequence

```
SQL> create table staff (
  2    emp_id number primary key,
  3    staff_name varchar2(100)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence emp_id_seq;

Sequence created.
```

Now, you can create a trigger that uses the sequence to populate the primary key

```
SQL> create trigger trg_emp_id
  2    before insert on staff
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select emp_id_seq.nextval
  6      into :new.emp_id
  7      from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Now, when you insert data, you woon't need to specify the `EMP_ID` column-- it will automatically be populated by the trigger

```
SQL> insert into staff( staff_name ) values ('Justin');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from staff;

    EMP_ID STAFF_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Justin
```

Comment: Hi, awesome can a sequence be used for different tables?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - You can, yes.  Conventionally, you would create separate sequences for each table though.  That reduces contention among sessions doing inserts on different tables, for example.

Comment: Justin, one quick question, when populating the tables, is it mandatory to list the attributes again? i just do it like;

INSERT INTO JOB VALUES (2,'Assistant Manager');

whats the difference?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: Justin might give you a more elaborated answer, and I'll just say that if you do that (omit the column names in INSERTs) in interactive mode, i.e. while you are working with the server typing in and sending your queries directly, it's up to you whether you specify the columns explicitly or not. But if you save your scripts for future use, you would likely do yourself or whoever else might be maintaining the database(s) in a couple of months or years a great favour by putting the column names in.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: I.e. there should be no issues from the performance point of view, and the difference lies more in the maintenance plane.

Comment: Can you please explain the 'from dual' part?

Comment: @kurdtpage - `dual` is just a table that has exactly 1 row in in that you can always select from.  Other database engines may allow you to write queries that don't have a `from` clause-- Oracle doesn't allow that but gives you `dual` instead if you want your query to just perform a calculation.  In recent Oracle versions, you could omit the `select` entirely and just do `:new.emp_id := emp_id_seq.nextval`.  In even newer versions, you can declare an autoincrementing column.

Answer (score 21):

Read this, Beautiful article.

how sequence [[auto increment in oracle]](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/19736/oracle-how-to-create-an-auto-increment-field-using-sequence/)

syntax

```
Create sequence sequence_name
start with value
increment by value
minvalue value
maxvalue value;
```

example

```
SQL> create table emp (
emp_id number(10),
fname varchar2(25),
lname varchar2(25),
constraint pk_emp_id PRIMARY KEY(emp_id)
);

SQL> Create sequence emp_sequence
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 10000;

SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Darvin','Johnson');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Mig','Andrews');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Alex','Martin');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Jon','paul');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Yatin','Bones');
```

in `emp_sequence.nextval` where `emp_sequence` is the name of sequence we created above and `nextval` is a function that is used to assign the `next number from emp_sequence to emp_id` column in emp table.

```
SQL> select * from emp;

  EMP_ID FNAME                     LNAME
---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
         1 Darvin                    Johnson
         2 Mig                       Andrews
         3 Alex                      Martin
         4 Jon                       paul
         5 Yatin                     Bones
```

Comment: Thanks, very neat, can I use the same sequence for any table that requires auto increment? also which part is the trigger?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos `yes` you can just give a proper `name` and `min/max values` as per your requirement.

Comment: this is using a sequence, which is essentially the same as initializing the value explicitly, just relying on the sequence for the value. autoincrement is a strategy that allow you to completely ignore the field and it is filling in automatically.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
create sequence seq_EmpID start with 1 increment by 1
```

```
 insert into Emp_Table values(seq_EmpID.nextval,'Ram')
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which version of Oracle you are using, but the following will work in 19c:

```
create table staff (
    emp_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    staff_name varchar2(100)
);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/19.3/java-driver-table/creating-tables-identity-column.html

The command above creates a system sequence that is automatically employed to populate the key value. you cannot drop the sequence created as it is a system sequence, but because of the dependency on the column when the table is dropped and the recycle bin purged it is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question!!
Probably sequence can be used in this way - also, I am not sure if there really is a difference :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE emp_id_seq MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 10;
```

Comment: This is almost identical to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

First creating the table :

```
sql-> create table item(id int primary key, name varchar(25),qty int, price int);
```

Now we want to make auto increment sequence to the first column i.e. `id`

```
sql-> CREATE SEQUENCE id MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 10; //system saves the last 10 items in temp memory
```

This will create auto increment.

Now we are inserting data:

```
sql-> insert into item VALUES(id.nextval,'ddcd',2,4);


sql-> insert into item VALUES(id.nextval,'ddcd',676,4);
```

Finally Displaying the table :

```
SQL> select * from item;

    ID NAME                             QTY      PRICE
```

---

```
     1 ddcd                               2          4
     2 ddcd                             676          4
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use a sequence for several tables, because the value of the sequence is inconsistent example:
we have two tables emp and depeartement:
If I use the sequence on emp I would have: ID_dept = 6 because the 5 is already used in the other table.

example :

```
SQL> insert into emp values(masequence.nextval,'aaa');
```

1 ligne crÚÚe.

```
SQL> insert into departement values(masequence.nextval,'aaa');
```

1 ligne crÚÚe.

```
SQL> select * from emp;

    ID_EMP NOM_EMP
---------- -------------------------
         5 aaa

SQL> select * from departement;

   ID_DEPT NOM_DEPT
---------- ----------
         6 aaa

SQL>
```

Comment: make sequence id separately for  different tables ,this will resolve your problem