# How to get the updated values in single insertion in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a single insert command which will get the records from one staging table and insert into the actual transaction table in oracle 10g. During this insertion, i want to increment one column value in transacation table irrespective of the value present in staging area.

Is there any such 'i++' kind of option available with sql programming? So that i can get the maximum value from the actual transaction table and will increment it.

Or else, any alternative way to resolve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Increment for Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733085/auto-increment-for-oracle)

Comment: @hemanth: Do refer to this question mentioned by Ben. It has very useful information for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sequences! Read more about sequences [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm) on Oracle documentation.

Sequences are independent database object that generate new number in a sequence specified.

E.g., if you merely say

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tblid_seq;
```

A new sequence named `tblid_seq` will be created, starting values from 1 and incrementing with 1.

You can use `nextval` and `currval` methods with a sequence.

E.g., everytime you use `tblid_seq.nextval`, you will get an incremented value.
When you use `tblid_seq.currval`, you will get the last value extracted by `tblid_seq.nextval`.

How to use it? Simple. In SQL:

```
INSERT INTO (tblid, val1) VALUES (tblid_seq.nextval, 'Some value');
```

In PL/SQL triggers, procedures, functions or anonymous block, you can use:

```
var1 := tblid_seq.nextval; -- var1 is of INTEGER data type.
```

A sequence is independent of any other database object, including the table you are using the sequence-generated value on. Sequences are also independent of transactions, you cannot ROLLBACK a sequence value. So use a sequence if you are okay with having gaps in the generated values.

Comment: But sequence will not help me out as i need to get the max value from existing table and need to increment it. Anyways, i can create a sequence starts with the max value of existing records and will increment it. However this will be triggered in multiple times and each time i have to create sequence with the max value taking from transaction tables. Will it be good idea to create sequences as many times as we required??

Comment: No you don't have to create the sequence again and again. As you are going to use the sequence on existing table, you can use `MINVALUE` clause of `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement. You can set `MINVALUE = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM tableName)`. After this, everytime you want to generate a new number just say `seq_name.nextval`. Your job is done.