# how to alter primary key to set Default value DEFAULT SYS_GUID() in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

I create table in oracle and I want add auto increment for my primary key

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_1"."PERSON" 
   ("ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PERSON_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"));
```

Using  Oracle sql develope when I want alter ID to get Auto Increment for primary key I get error  ORA-02262: ORA-932

I have two raw in table

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON  
MODIFY (ID DEFAULT SYS_GUID() );
```

Comment: [SYS_GUID()](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/SQLRF/functions201.htm#SQLRF06120) does not return a number, so the data type doesn't match. Do you actually want a GUID, rather than a number from a [sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm), assigned via a trigger? (Unless you're on 12c, which has [auto-increment functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF55657) now).

Comment: I want get auto increment for id in table.(11g).so only I can use  a sequence thanks

Comment: In 11g you'd usually [use a sequence and a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9733085/266304) for an 'auto-incrementing' number column, particularly for a PK. I'm not sure though if you want a number or a GUID. They are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: my answer and examples are using Oracle 11g)

## Reason for the issue/error

The Oracle error `ORA-02262` is thrown when there are [inconsistent data types](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00932.php). In your case, when creating the table you specify that the ID column is of type `NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_1"."PERSON" 
("ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, ...
```

The [`SYS_GUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions175.htm#SQLRF06120) function in Oracle "generates and returns a globally unique identifier (`RAW` value) made up of 16 bytes). The documentation then states that the 16-byte `RAW` value can be represented by a **32-character hexadecimal representation**, or `VARCHAR2(32)`.

For this reason, when `SYS_GUID()` is used as the default value of a column in Oracle, the result is often stored as a 32-byte `VARCHAR` or `VARCHAR2`:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_1.PERSON (
  ID VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL ENABLE DEFAULT SYS_GUID(),
  ...
);
```

## Solution(s)

If *altering the data type of the column* is a suitable solution, the code below will successfully alter the table to store `SYS_GUID()` values as identifiers:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_1.PERSON MODIFY( 
  ID VARCHAR2(32) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() 
);
```

If you must have a numeric value as the ID in your table, there is an excellent answer here:

> [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296469/2479241)

Comment: `sys_guid()` should be stored in a `raw(16)`, not a varchar

Answer (score -1):

The oracle show this error means:
    // *Cause:  New column datatype causes type-checking error for existing column
    //          default value expression.
   // *Action: Remove the default value expression or don't alter the column
   //          datatype.

are you not using Sequences for it ??

Comment: is there any way I can alter table .No there is no Sequence

Comment: Alex is correct, sys_guid() works with the RAW datatype, so you can use the sequences for it.