# How to define a auto increment column using oracle 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Ho can i define a integer auto increment with oracle 11g?This is my code with mysql `user_id int(6) not null auto_increment primary key` how can i have this line with oracle?Because i've already the same database in mysql now i want to build the same structure with oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Increment for Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733085/auto-increment-for-oracle)

Comment: for oracle 12c+ follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296469/10531665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_user;
```

The above will auto increment by 1, and start at 1.

To insert values using this sequence, you can do the following (for example):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (user_id) VALUES (seq_user.NEXTVAL);
```

To automate this process, you could reference the sequence in a trigger on the table, that adds this value on an insert automatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN
  IF(inserting)
  THEN
    :NEW.USER_ID := seq_user.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: In oracle this is called a surrogate key.