# Trying to auto-increment in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, primary-key

I am trying to create an auto-incrementing primary key for a table but Im having no luck. This is in Oracle 11g and I am seriously missing the MySQL auto-increment command. PrimkeyID is the column I am trying to use as the primary key. This is a intersect table for a many to many relationship. At any rate, the error says that I am missing a key word just within the beginning of the primary key parenthesis. Also I don't have the privilege level required to do triggers, which appear to be important for incrementing in Oracle.

```
create table SITE_JUNC
(
primkeyID number,
FKsuperpave varchar(30),
FKcont_mix varchar(30),
)
;
alter table site_junc 
add constraint primary key(create sequence primkeyID incement by 1),

add constraint FKsuperpave foreign key(mix_id_superpave)
references SMGR_CONT_MIX(ContMix),

add constraint FKcont_mix foreign key(mix_id_cont_mix)
references SUPERPAVE(SuperMix)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Increment for Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733085/auto-increment-for-oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I just looked at that post a minute ago and I don't have the ability to do triggers. Im an analyst and I don't have the level of privilege.

Comment: Then you are out of luck with Oracle 11 but if you can create tables, you usually can create triggers as well. What happens when you try to create the trigger?

Comment: When I try to create a trigger on a table I just created I get the error message ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.

Comment: I just did the same steps as outlined in the Auto Increment for Oracle post mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

First, sequences are objects disassociated from the table.
You have to first create the sequence, and THEN the table (not necessarily in that order).

```
Create sequence seq_table;
```

Then, at the insert statement, use the seq_table.nextval (or by using triggers).
If you don't like this solution, you can use GUID (i personally don't like it) :

```
create table SITE_JUNC
(primkey number RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() PRIMARY KEY,
....)
```

Starting Oracle 12c, you have Identity columns.

Comment: At Renato Afonso that makes sense thank you ill give it a shot

Comment: I would recommend the sequence over the GUID